# Set "default" monitor

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display, monitor

I would like to be able to set my "default" monitor to be my external 25' monitor instead of my laptop one when I have my external monitor connected.

Many applications always open on the laptops monitor instead of the "big" one. Currently, the only way I know to disable this behavior is to disable the laptop monitor, however, as I use a laptop stand to bring it higher, Id like to be able to use my laptop monitor as a "secondary" monitor, without dock (launcher) and without any windows opening on it.

The only way for a window to reach it would be to actually manually grab it and drag it over.

Some known applications that ALWAYS open on the laptop monitor and drive me crazy: Slack, Rocket Chat, Thunderbird, Sky, System Settings, Guake (specially annoying since i cant move it).

Comment: Did you try `xrandr` with `primary` option ?

Comment: I did. It said it couldnt find VGA0, not sure how to "query" for available options.

Comment: `xrandr -q` - to query available outputs

Comment: Fantastic, I think that resolved it. I posted an answer. If you'd like post your own and I will accept it and delete mine, since it was based on your suggestion.

Comment: There you go, I deleted my answer and promoted yours to the correct one. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your external monitor output using `xrandr`

```
xrandr -q
```

Now let's assume your monitor is connected using HDMI1 port

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary
```

For making it persist run:

```
tee -a $HOME/.xprofile <<< "xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary"
```